# How can I change the name of a task that Celery sends to a backend?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery

I have built a queue system using Celery that accepts web requests and executes some tasks to act on those requests. I'm using Redis as the backend for Celery, but I imagine this question would apply to all backends.

Celery is returning the task name as `celery-task-meta-<task ID>` and storing it in the backend. This is meaningless to me.  How can I change the name of the result that celery sends to Redis? I have searched through all of [Celery's documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) to try to figure out how to do this.

The Redis CLI monitor is showing that Celery is using the SETEX method and sending the following input:

> "SETEX" "celery-task-meta-dd32ded3-00aa-4884-8b21-42f8332e7fac"
>   "86400" "{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\", \"result\": {\"mode\": \"staging\",
>   \"123\": 50}, \"traceback\": null, \"children\": [], \"task_id\":
>   \"dd32ded3-00aa-4884-8b21-42f8332e7fac\", \"date_done\":
>   \"2019-05-09T16:44:12.826951\", \"parent_id\":
>   \"2e99d958-cd5a-4700-a7c2-22c90f387f28\"}"

The `"result": {...}` that you can see in the SETEX command above is what the task returns. I would like the SETEX to be more along the lines of:
`"SETEX" "mode-staging-123-50-SUCCESS" "{...}"`, so that when I view all my keys in Redis, the name of the key is informational to me.

Here's another example view of the keys in my Redis cache that are meaningless:

[image: redis keys]

Answer (score 3):

You can't change this. The task key is created by [`ResultConsumer`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/42a5befd07a94e359e722fd4f3aecc871cf1e31d/celery/backends/redis.py#L84) class which Redis backend uses. `ResultConsumer` then delegates creation of the task key to [`BaseKeyValueStoreBackend`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/42a5befd07a94e359e722fd4f3aecc871cf1e31d/celery/backends/base.py#L551) class. The `get_key_for_task` method which actually creates the key uses hardcoded `task_keyprefix` set to `celery-task-meta-`. So, to change the behaviour, you would have to subclass these classes. There's not configuration option for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the sake of accuracy, are you saying it's impossible to change it? Couldn't one simply patch Celery to dynamically create a new task name inside of the `BaseKeyValueStoreBackend` class?

That's obviously a lot more work than it's worth, so I think I will go with something else.

Comment: That's what I tried to say. It's not completelly impossible, just a lot of work. Also, you would have to maintain your modifications.